# jQuery load's callback does not fire when paramaters are provided?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, callback, load

The callback function of jQuery's load does not execute when I post parameters to the server.

This causes a server error, but the callback function executes:

```
chassisLookupDialog.load('../Workflow/FindChassisDialog/', function (response, status, xhr) {

    console.log("Response", response, status, xhr);

    chassisLookupDialog.open();
});
```

This works, the paramaters get to the server and no error is thrown, but the callback function never executes:

```
chassisLookupDialog.load('../Workflow/FindChassisDialog/', {
        dataCenterID: dataCenterID,
        bladeTemplateID: bladeTemplateID,
        selectedChassisID: selectedChassisID,
        selectedSlotNumber: selectedSlotNumber
    }, function (response, status, xhr) {

    console.log("Response", response, status, xhr);

    chassisLookupDialog.open();
});
```

Here's my controller:

```
public ActionResult FindChassisDialog(int dataCenterID, int bladeTemplateID, int selectedChassisID, int selectedSlotNumber)
{
    FindChassisDialogModel findChassisDialogModel = new FindChassisDialogModel();

    return View("FindChassisDialog", findChassisDialogModel);
}
```

and if I inspect the server's response I see that all the HTML is properly formed. Not sure why my callback would not be executing... any ideas?

This calls the error event with the view's html as the error data:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '../Workflow/FindChassisDialog/',
    data: {
        dataCenterID: dataCenterID,
        bladeTemplateID: bladeTemplateID,
        selectedChassisID: selectedChassisID,
        selectedSlotNumber: selectedSlotNumber
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("Success:", data);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.error("Error:", error);
    }
});
```

Comment: When parameters are provided, `load` method sends request as `post` and when parameters are absent, `load` sends request as `get` method. May be your server is failing to handle `post` method.

Comment: Yeah, agreed, just not really sure how/why. I see the response come back successfully, there's no errors or failed requests. I just see it return the view and then never hit the callback. I have other, working examples where I send 1 paramater and this works fine. I haven't spotted the difference yet.

Comment: Try using `complete` and `success/error` events of `$.ajax`

Comment: Edited my ajax request into the post. The 'error' is called with responseText being the HTML for the view.

Comment: Try adding `dataType : html` in request. Also, check the errorText. `error` callback has 3 arguements `( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )`

Comment: I suspect what's going on is that MVC won't do the same magic with a POST as a GET when returning a View so i'll probably have to set the HTML manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `$.ajax` request get rid of the following line:

```
dataType: 'json',
```

I mean, you are telling jQuery that this AJAX request will return JSON, and yet you are returning HTML from your controller action (`return View(...)`). So when jQuery attempts to parse this as JSON it obviously bombs out and your `success` callback will never be executed.

So:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../Workflow/FindChassisDialog/',
    data: {
        dataCenterID: dataCenterID,
        bladeTemplateID: bladeTemplateID,
        selectedChassisID: selectedChassisID,
        selectedSlotNumber: selectedSlotNumber
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("Success:", data);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.error("Error:", error);
    }
});
```

By the way, hardcoding an url like that is just plain wrong:

```
url: '../Workflow/FindChassisDialog/',
```

You should always be using url helpers in an ASP.NET MVC application when dealing with urls.

And one more thing: why are you returning an entire view (instead of partial) from a controller action that gets invoked wit AJAX?

Comment: I was using $.load before, though... Surely I should be able to load a view while passing multiple parameters. I understand why the $.ajax doesn't work because of the dataType, and I know how to manually load the HTML response, but I'm shocked MVC isn't doing this for me if I need to pass more than 1 parameter.

Comment: And I also understand that the URLs are horrible, but I'm working under technical debt (the entire project was created during MVC1 and has been slowly upgraded). I don't have the liberty to standardize them all currently.

Comment: Alright, so what happened when you got rid of the `dataType: 'json'` setting from your `$.ajax` call? Also the fact that you are working under a technical debt is absolutely not an excuse to not start reducing this debt. Personally if I see a hardcoded url like that I would immediately improve it before even thinking of continuing to be contributing on this project. It's absolutely not an excuse that the project was created under ASP.NET MVC 1. Even under that version there were Url.* helpers that could have been used.

Comment: If I remove the dataType json from the AJAX request then I am able to receive HTML in the response. Then, I'd have to call jQuery.html(response); to load the HTML into the element. This is not as intuitive as just $.load'ing on the element which is where my confusion arises. And yes, I understand that, as well, but the argument is for consistencies sake. If I don't have the time to go change every instance of how we currently do URLs then I shouldn't be changing only /some/ of them. I'd rather have wrong-but-consistent than half-consistent half-wrong.

Comment: You could inspect with a javascript debugging tool such as FireBug the difference in the request payload and verb being sent between the working $.ajax call and the non working element.load call. Normally there shouldn't be any if you are sending parameters to the element.load call as that would send an AJAX request. What do you see in FireBug when you use element.load? What status code does the server return?

Comment: :( It turns out I'm just a huge idiot. The load function being called was someone's custom implementation of load which then calls jQuery load... but it only accepts 2 paramaters (not an optional 3)... which explains everything. Argh. Thank you for the insight, though, it's appreciated.